# select the month part only in a DATE datatype column using CI active record?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

How could I  select the month part only in a DATE datatype column
using CodeIgniter's active record class? What would be my query?

Im also confused what do i need to use,.. LIKE or WHERE clause?

Please give me examples.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ], please.

Comment: [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this snippet,

```
$where = "MONTH(dateColumn) = 4"; // comparing on April
$this->db->where($where);
```

- [MONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

According to `Active Record` Doc, the `WHERE` uses for methods.

- Simple key/value method
- Custom key/value method
- Associative array method
- Custom string (*which is the example above*)

SOURCE

- [Active Record Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: this is great not sure why both of us has to come up with the same month =) I am sure I am not as fast as you though

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`month`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month):

```
MONTH(urdate) = 4
```